# Скачать файл с помощью AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, post, javascript

Добрый день. Ситуация такая:
Есть сервер. На нем есть ссылка нажав на которую происходит генерация контента (перегоняется DJVU в TIFF) и выдается TIFF файл. Генерация происходит долго. До минуты (все это время в браузере пишется "Ожидание %host%"). Затем вылазит окошко "сохранить как" и готовый файл скачивается. Вопрос: можно ли как-то на время генерации (от клика до окна "сохранить как") выводит информационное сообщение (к примеру крутить ГИФку от начала, а по окну - убрать ее)? Хотелось бы, по возможности, через jQuery AJAX. Но создаю я AJAX запрос посылаю его, возвращается ответ, срабатывает success, но "сохранить как" не происходит. Можно ли как-то ему объяснить, что неплохо было бы сохранить все это? Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Спасибо за ответы и за участие.

**UPD**
С сервера идет картинка TIFF. Но идет она через минуту. Эту минуту надо отловить. Если применить такой код

```
$.post(URL, PARAMS, function(data) { alert(data.length); });
```

То по запросу можно ГИФ включить, по success закрыть, но как заставить его пришедшую data сохранить в файл? Alert вываливается и все. Инфу надо как-то дальше сохранить. Если использовать старый способ отправки через FORM то происходит смена URL на файл и отловить появление "save as" не представляю как.

Comment: @QuitLN, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Что конкретно с сервера ты забираешь-то? Парсишь готовую ссылку после ожидания или как?

Comment: Что стоит со стороны сервера? PHP?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Самописный сервер. Но базовые возможности доступны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может Вам подойдёт такое решение:

Вы со страницы вызываете ajax запрос на генерацию картинку, и в фоне ждете ответ, но в ответе вы отдаёте не саму картинку, а ссылку на неё, и в методе success прописываете `location=data`

```
$.ajax({url:"you url for generation"}).success(function(data){ location = data; });
```

Точнее наверное надо создать новое окно с этим локейшеном:

```
window.open(data,'','…');
```

Ну и соответственно всякие крутилки включаете и выключаете перед вызовом аякса и в суксессе.

Через фреймы всё прекрасно отлавливается:

можно посмотреть [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/9V4hF/9/)

**HTML**

```
<button>test</button>
<div id="loader"></div>
<div class="iframe">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#loader").text("Loading...");
            $("iframe").ready(function(){$("#loader").text("Loading... started...");});    
            $("iframe").load(function(){$("#loader").text("Loaded!");});
            $("iframe").attr("src","http://jfarcand.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/untitled.jpg");
        });
}
);​
```

Comment: Да, метод рассматривался. Но проблема в том, что картинка не хранится физически негде. Она генерируется и сразу выдается в поток. Промежуточного хранения хотелось бы избежать (придется много переписывать) :(

Comment: Вам решать, но это плохое решение в принципе - минутное ожидание ответа от сервера может рубиться клиентской стороной как таймаут в зависимости от настроек сети/браузера/прокси/провайдера и т.д.

Попробуйте тогда реализовать через фреймы?

Comment: Через фреймы беда в том, что не получается отловить момент начала скачки файла =( onload не собирается работать =\

Comment: Смотрите обновление ответа.

Comment: Метод отличный. Но как я понял работает только для inline документов. Если подставить ему .exe файлик: уже в "Loaded!" не встает. Мои TIFF-ки как раз так и выгружаются. Видимо простого решения нету. Спасибо за помощь !

Comment: Ну можно ещё топорной затычкой сделать:

на сервере взводить флаг когда отправили ответ, а из основного окна переодически пинговать сервер на этот флаг - как взашёл - так значит loaded

Answer (score 0):

**Как скачать файл после получения его по ajax**

Удобно когда файл долго создаётся и нужно показать preloader

Пример при отправке веб-формы:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('#loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'binary',
            xhrFields: {
                'responseType': 'blob'
            },
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                $('#loader').hide();
                // if(data.type.indexOf('text/html') != -1){//Если вместо файла получили страницу с ошибкой
                //     var reader = new FileReader();
                //     reader.readAsText(data);
                //     reader.onload = function() {alert(reader.result);};
                //     return;
                // }
                var link = document.createElement('a'),
                    filename = 'file.xlsx';
                // if(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition')){//имя файла
                //     filename = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                //     filename=filename.match(/filename="(.*?)"/)[1];
                //     filename=decodeURIComponent(escape(filename));
                // }
                link.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
                link.download = filename;
                link.click();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Не обязательный функционал закомментирован для упрощения примера.

Не требуется создавать временные файлы на сервере.

На jQuery v2.2.4 всё работает. На старой версии будет ошибка:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'blob').
```